# Gvim changes Pmenu colours when using :source command

Tags: vim, colors, clang, highlight

I have the Taglist and clang_complete plugins installed. When starting gvim and manually opening the files, the colours of the autocompletion are set properly, as defined in my .vimrc (only the last two lines are what I'm talking about - posting the whole file in case the error is caused by something else):

```
syntax on
colorscheme slate
set number  "start with line numbering enabled.
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set autoindent
set guifont=Monospace\ 11
set showcmd
nnoremap <expr> gp '`[' . strpart(getregtype(), 0, 1) . '`]'
filetype plugin indent on
filetype plugin on
map <C-n> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
highlight Pmenu ctermbg=Gray ctermfg=White
highlight PmenuSel ctermbg=Black ctermfg=White
let Tlist_Inc_Winwidth = 0
let Tlist_Use_Right_Window = 1
autocmd vimenter,BufNewFile,BufReadPost,FileReadPost *.cpp,*.c,*.objc,*.ch,*.objcpp Tlist
let g:lua_complete_omni = 1
highlight Pmenu guibg=gray10 guifg=LightSteelBlue4
highlight PmenuSel guibg=gray10 guifg=LightSteelBlue1
```

Then I make a session using `:mksession ~/.server.vim`

When I run:
`gvim -S ~/.server.vim`
then the colours are back to the original pink, which really doesn't work well with my colour scheme.

What do I do to keep the colours for the clang_complete popup as defined in my .vimrc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the session is sourced after your `~/.vimrc`, it probably overrides your special highlightings. In general, these need to be re-applied after colorscheme changes. Use the following function in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
function! s:SetHighlightings()
    highlight Pmenu ctermbg=Gray ctermfg=White
    highlight PmenuSel ctermbg=Black ctermfg=White
    highlight Pmenu guibg=gray10 guifg=LightSteelBlue4
    highlight PmenuSel guibg=gray10 guifg=LightSteelBlue1
endfunction
call s:SetHighlightings()
autocmd ColorScheme * call <SID>SetHighlightings()
```

If that still doesn't fix the problem, change the triggers to `:autocmd ColorScheme,SessionLoadPost ...`

Comment: I had to add 'endfunction' before the call. After that, it worked like a charm - thanks a lot!